# Yahoo OAUTH Login for website

Tags: authentication, oauth, yahoo

Friends,

I have implemented yahoo login for website using OAUTH

I am using https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=j5nyp6 to present the permission screen.

However every time the user needs to allow permission for the application. Ideally if the permission is given one time, further requests need not require permission unless the given permission is revoked. (Google and Twitter login works in this way which I could implement)

Is this the only way Yahoo login can be done or is there any workaround

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the Access Token? Or are you forcing the user through the full OAuth flow everytime?

If you are storing the Access Token, then that is all that is needed to access the services after the initial OAuth process.

Comment: I'm struggling to solve same issue. Can you please briefly explain how should I store the access token and how to access the services without going through full OAuth flow everytime? I'll really appreciate that.